# does a C++ locale have an associated timezone? And if yes, how do you access it?

Tags: c++, locale

I've done a little research on this, and I have pretty convincing evidence for the
answer YES, and the answer NO. I'm not sure which side to believe.

First, the documentation I've found on cppreference.com, and 
http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf appear to say nothing about this.
I take that as evidence that locales do NOT support a timezone.

But https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/time_get/get and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/time_put/put
both say:

> %z writes offset from UTC in the ISO 8601 format (e.g. -0430), or no
>   characters if the time zone information is not available  %Z writes
>   time zone name or abbreviation, or no characters if the time zone
>   information is not available (locale dependent)

which appears to suggest there is a timezone SOMETIMES associated with
a locale () object.

Now, if you take the locale en_US.utf8 (one of my favorites ;-)), there really isn't any sensible
timezone to associate (the United States contains at least 4 or more timezones).

So time to get empirical.

I ran the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <locale>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    //  locale l;
    locale                l = locale::classic ();
    tm                    when{};
    const time_put<char>& tmput = use_facet<time_put<char>> (l);
    ostringstream         oss;
    oss.imbue (l);
    static const string   kTZOffsetPattern_{"%z"};
    tmput.put (oss, oss, ' ', &when, kTZOffsetPattern_.c_str (), kTZOffsetPattern_.c_str () + kTZOffsetPattern_.length ());
    cout << oss.str ();
    return 0;
}
```

On Linux (ubuntu), this gave the answer I expected, +0000 (OK, I also wouldn't have been surprised with error or empty string).

But on Windows (visual studio.net 2k17 - 15.8.7) - this gives:
    -0500

Yes, as you may have guessed, I'm testing this in the eastern timezone. But I still would have expected
0, or the empty string (especially for the locale::classic() case).

Comment: No.  But you can use [Howard Hinnant's time zone library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html) to access any IANA time zone and discover your local time zone.  This library has been voted into the C++20 draft specification, but can be used with C++11 or later.  In this library the time zone is not coupled to a `std::locale`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Direct Answer to your question**

> Does a C++ locale have an associated time zone?

No.

Nor will it in the future.  As correctly noted in the question, for many locales it wouldn't make sense as the geographical area represented by the locale can have more than one time zone.

The C standard does say in the spec for `strftime`:

> `%Z` is replaced by the locale’s time zone name or abbreviation, or by no characters if no
>   time zone is determinable. `[tm_isdst]`

But the C spec for `struct lconv` provides no such member to store that information.  The spec does allow implementations to add such members, but   in practice, implementations do not store that information with the C locale.

The C++ locale facets `time_put` and `time_get` define themselves in terms of the C spec for `strftime`, the POSIX spec for `strptime`, and some additions, which do not include a time zone name or abbreviation.

The POSIX spec for `strftime` is much more detailed than the C spec, and removes the association with "locale":

> `Z` Replaced by the timezone name or abbreviation, or by no bytes if no timezone information exists. `[ tm_isdst]`

The POSIX spec for `struct lconv` is also much more detailed than the C spec, but still does not provide storage for a time zone name or abbreviation.

But the future does bring hope of more easily and effectively accessing information about time zones, at least in C++.

Prior to C++20, C++ has knowledge of:

1. A single time standard: UTC, which is closely modeled by [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).
2. A single time zone:  the "local time zone" set by the user or administrator of the computer.  UTC can also be used as a local time zone.

As detailed above, the local time zone is *not* part of the C++ (or C) locale data.  The locale data *does* include some calendrical data such as:

- Full and abbreviated weekday names.
- Full and abbreviated month names.
- Local conventional formats for displaying date and time (e.g. year, month, day ordering).

The UTC offset (`%z`) and time zone abbreviation (`%Z`) *may* be available, but would be stored as part of the local time zone data, instead of with the current locale data, largely because there is not a good one-to-one mapping between time zones and locales.

**Explanation of what happened with the code presented in the OP's question**

In your example:  `tm when{};` zeroes all members of the `tm`, including `tm_isdst`.  When `tm_isdst` is zero, this means Daylight Saving Time is known to not be in effect, for this particular `tm`.

`tm` is also allowed to have members not specified by the standard.  A popular extension is to have a member `tm_gmtoff` which holds the UTC offset in seconds.  If your Linux implementation has such a member, `tm when{};` would have set it to 0 seconds.  If your Windows implementation does *not* have such a member, the UTC offset of the local time zone would be stored elsewhere.  This explains the differences you're seeing, and both implementations are conforming.

---

**Helpful information about how to access time zones since C++ locales do not provide access**

In the C++20 spec, there exists a new type called `std::chrono::time_zone`.  One of the member functions of `time_zone` is:

```
template<class Duration> sys_info get_info(const sys_time<Duration>& st) const;
```

`sys_time<Duration>` is just a `system_clock::time_point`, but of *any* precision.  So you give a `time_zone` a `time_point`, and you get back a `sys_info` which contains all kinds of useful information about *that* `time_zone` at *that* `time_point`:

```
struct sys_info
{
    sys_seconds begin;
    sys_seconds end;
    seconds     offset;
    minutes     save;
    string      abbrev;
};
```

- The range `[begin, end)` tells you for what times this information is valid (these are UTC time points).
- `offset` is the `time_zone`'s current UTC offset in `seconds`.
- If `save != 0min`, the `time_zone` is currently considered to be in daylight savings.
- The `time_zone`'s current abbreviation is stored in `abbrev`.

Additionally, there is a non-member function:

```
const time_zone* current_zone();
```

which returns a pointer to your current local time zone.  Putting this all together, here is a C++20 program that prints out interesting information about your current local time zone:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    std::cout << current_zone()->get_info(system_clock::now()) << '\n';
}
```

This just output for me:

```
2018-03-11 07:00:00
2018-11-04 06:00:00
-04:00:00
01:00
EDT
```

If you like, you can experiment with this part of C++20 using C++11, 14 or 17 by using [Howard Hinnant's timezone library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date).  This library puts everything in namespace `date` instead of `std::chrono`.

You can also get information on *any* [IANA time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), for example:

```
#include "date/tz.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    std::cout << locate_zone("Australia/Sydney")->get_info(system_clock::now()) << '\n';
}
```

which just output for me:

```
2018-10-06 16:00:00
2019-04-06 16:00:00
11:00:00
01:00
AEDT
```

Note though that even in C++20, time zones and locales are *not* coupled.  It just doesn't make sense to do so.

Comment: this is helpful and interesting, but doesn't appear to answer my core question.

Yes or No - is there a timezone associated with a locale object? 

WHen I take a locale, and a struct tm (which has no timezone info) and print to a string using the %z%Z format strings, I get back timezone info. EITHER that comes from the tm (which it cannot) or from the locale (which is the question) - or the current OS timezone or just its random nonsense. 

I get the caveats that lots of stuff is left implementation defined, but I'm wondering if ANY of the above is actually SPECIFICATION-defined?

Comment: To a degree your comment that prior to C++20 C++ only has xxx knowlege of timezones does answer my question (since you didnt mention locale). Do you expect that also to apply to C++, and can you please clarify / confirm, there is no timezone information associated with a locale (beyond the ability to format/print/describe/react to the current system timezone settings)?

Comment: The local time zone is **not** part of the C++ (or C) locale data as specified by the C and C++ standards (C89/99/11 and C++98/03/11/14/17).  It is possible that a platform could add time zone data to a locale as an extension, but I'm not aware of any such platform.  I can speak with the highest confidence about the libc++/LLVM implementation because I authored all of the `std::locale` for Apple (a BSD based system).  I've also written code to detect the currently set local time zone (`current_zone()`) on Linux, macOS, iOS and Windows, and none of that code checks the currently set locale.

Answer (score 3):

> does a C++ locale have an associated timezone?

All aspects of current timezone are implementation defined.

The exact wording of `%Z` specifier from C99 (C++ delegates C library function specification to the C standard) is:

> is replaced by the locale’s time zone name or abbreviation, or by no characters if no time zone is determinable.

It seems a bit ambiguous. One interpretation is indeed that locale may affect the time zone. Another, which doesn't quite fit the wording as well, would be that the locale affects the name or abbreviation of the time zone. Regardless, there appears to be no guarantee that the time zone isn't affected by the locale, although I would not expect that it were.

---

> how do you access it?

As far as I know, you can't using standard library utilities. Not directly anyway, and no way of modifying it.

A way to print the current timezone is to use the `%z` or `%Z` format specifiers of `strftime`/`put_time`/`time_put` as you've shown.

There is a way to get the zone difference as an integer as well. `std::mktime` unparses a `std::tm` structure into a timestamp according to the locale, while `std::gmtime` parses a timestamp into `std::tm` structure according to the UTC, so if you start with the epoch and combine those two, you will get the difference of the current locale time zone and the UTC in seconds.

```
std::time_t t = 0;
std::cout << -1 * std::mktime(std::gmtime(&t));
```

Comment: I guess my original post didn't make it clear enough, but the code I provided actually is A WAY of extracting the timezone from the locale. It's just that it didn't work the way the documentation said on either compiler I tried (latest gcc and latest visual studio). And of course its a crazy awkward maybe misunderstood way of accessing the timezone.

Comment: @LewisPringle `It's just that it didn't work the way the documentation said` How does the behaviour differ from what the documentation said?

Comment: The docs for "%z writes offset from UTC in the ISO 8601 format (e.g. -0430), or no characters if the time zone information is not available". On C locale (which I believe has no sensible timezone) - should write no characters (empty string). On glibc/ubuntu it wrote +0000, and on windows it wrote -0500. Those are pretty clearly bad answers (unless you believe on unix C locale in GMT and on windows C locale is EST timezone. Not 100% clearly broken (cuz not clearly defined what timezone is for those locales). But at least surprising.

Comment: @LewisPringle there is no such guarantee that you're assuming that the local time zone wouldn't be available in the C locale.

Answer (score 0):

The relevant passage of the C standard (which the C++ standard relies upon) says

> %z is replaced by the offset from UTC in the ISO 8601 format ‘‘−0430’’ (meaning 4 hours 30 minutes behind UTC, west of Greenwich), or by no characters if no time zone is determinable. [tm_isdst]
>
> %Z is replaced by the locale’s time zone name or abbreviation, or by no characters if no time zone is determinable. [tm_isdst]

Note that time zone *name* is said to be locale dependent, but time zone *offset* is not.

Cppreference needs to fix their sloppy wording.

Comment: Cppreference wording is what you quoted, only "locale's" is replaced by "(locale-dependent)".

Comment: @Cubbi it isn't clear what "(locale dependent)" in this wording refers to. Is the availability of TZ data locale dependent, or just the TZ name? It did confuse OP and it confuses me. OTOH "writes a locale-dependent time zone name or abbreviation" is so much clearer and cleaner.